# Send SMS via Twilio npm package - Error cannot find - Error: Cannot find module './webhooks'

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to send a simple SMS via Twilios npm package, I have tried some of the current packages out there with no avail. So I thought I would go the good old fashioned npm route. That also seems to fail at the following server error message:

> W20170306-13:50:46.118(-8)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module './webhooks'
>   W20170306-13:50:46.118(-8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:123:19)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.119(-8)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.twilio.lib.index.js (packages/modules.js:342:16)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.119(-8)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.119(-8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.120(-8)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.server.js (server/server.js:3:14)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.120(-8)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.120(-8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
>   W20170306-13:50:46.121(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/nicholas/Desktop/meteor/esoLounge/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:15:1
>   W20170306-13:50:46.123(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/nicholas/Desktop/meteor/esoLounge/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
>   W20170306-13:50:46.124(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)

This is my server code:

```
let accountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa',
    authToken = 'a91xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa',
    twilio = require("../node_modules/twilio/lib"),
    client = new twilio.RestClient(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    to: '+15555555551', 
    from: '+15555555551'
}, function(err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

I am also open to working solutions outside of Twilio, if there is any. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are using npm packages correctly with meteor. You should not use require and should use imports instead. Refer to the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html)

Comment: Just as @jordanwillis has stated. You should not be using require in Meteor for importing node packaged. Read the meteor guide and use 'import'; import Twilio from 'twilio';

Answer (score 0):

Why are you requiring twilio like that (with the file path)? Node/npm/require handles all that for you automatically and I imagine that's where your problem is coming from.

Just do:

`var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);`

Comment: I'll give that a try, I was following their tut which had the long path.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign Strange! I got that code just now from node/twilio documentation: https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/2.1.0/index.html#quickstart but it looks like they do it differently in different examples. If you still get the same error, then twilio isn't your problem and it's something else in your code, possibly to do with meteor.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign if you read the error, look at the bottom, you need to look at app.js line 15 AND boot.js line 303. Is it the exact same error?

Comment: yup, same error. goes away as soon as I remove the require call.

Comment: @NicholasByDesign can you give a bit more context? Like the block that contains your twilio code? I don't know much about meteor and build process though. What it looks like is for some reason `require` is searching in the wrong place. You should confirm that the file `webhooks.js` is at `../node_modules/twilio/lib`. If so, then meteor/node/something is having trouble looking in the right place.

Comment: I am a Twilio developer evangelist. Can I ask which tutorial you were using that had that long path like that? I'd like to get it updated.

Comment: @philnash hey phil, right here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node,  at the bottom the "Installation" section it says to require twilio as such `var twilio = require("path/to/twilio-node/lib");` but there is a code example directly below that uses `require('twilio');` a little confusing. Thanks!